# Validate Email Address Columns in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Good afternoon,

Create a field to store an email.

The field is called "Client Contact for NewsLetter"

the valication formula has a syntax error.

Your kind help.

```
=AND(
ISERROR(FIND(" ", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],1)),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)),
    FALSE,
    AND(
        ISERROR(FIND("@",[Client Contact for NewsLetter], FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)+1)),
        IF(ISERROR(FIND(".", [Client Contact for NewsLetter], FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)+2)),
            FALSE,
            FIND(".", [Client Contact for NewsLetter], FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)+2) < LEN([Client Contact for NewsLetter])
        )
    )
)  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula out, I have tried to simply it by removing the nested IF conditions and flatten it out using AND. Let me know if it helps.

```
=AND(
ISERROR(FIND(" ",[Client Contact for NewsLetter])),
NOT(ISERROR(FIND("@",[Client Contact for NewsLetter],2))),
ISERROR(FIND("@",[Client Contact for NewsLetter], FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)+1)),
NOT(ISERROR(FIND(".",[Client Contact for NewsLetter]))),
FIND(".", [Client Contact for NewsLetter], FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)+2),
FIND(".", [Client Contact for NewsLetter], FIND("@", [Client Contact for NewsLetter],2)+2) < LEN([Client Contact for NewsLetter]))
```

Comment: Thanks! you are great! I only add that I should have changed the "," towards ";".